# Group Chart with multiple layers in ChartJS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I've search over the internet about this, but I didn't see the solution for this. I'm trying to implement a group chart with layers separation. Basically, 1 bar and has 2 or more data (or color).

I've also tried this link https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/mixed.html, but it is just a mix chart types. Please see the image below for the sample output that I want to achieve.

[image]

So the picture above has a total of 3 colors, blue, and mixed yellow and orange. Any idea for this?

Comment: If I understand correctly you want one dataset to be shown in a single bar and another two datasets in stacked bar chart form?

Comment: Hi @KunalKhivensara. Yes, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I really doubt if that's possible since stacked bar chart is also a type of bar chart and to create a mixed chart using chart.js you have to specify the different type which is same for the stacked and simple bar chart.

Comment: Hi @KunalKhivensara. What do you mean by stacked bar by the way? Is that the horizontal one you're talking about?

Comment: In my first comment I asked if you need to show stacked bar and simple bar together you said 'Yes'. Now you are asking what is stacked bar? that's weird. The blue colors bar in your example are simple bars and the combination of orange and yellow in a single bar is a stacked bar.

Comment: Oh. Alright. I was just confused with your 2nd comment. Okay then, any solution for this?

Comment: I have posted a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option to create stacked group chart in chart.js where you can have to specify the stack property based on you grouping need. See the below code or the fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/4h6dm2ny/

Hope it helps!

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["13Aug", "14Aug", "15Aug"],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Blue',
        stack: 'Stack 0',
        data: [240, 270, 1320],
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
      },
      {
        label: 'Orange',
        stack: 'Stack 1',
        data: [0, 300, 1520],
        backgroundColor: 'orange',
      },
      {
        label: 'Yellow',
        data: [1500, 700, 200],
        stack: 'Stack 1',
        backgroundColor: 'yellow',
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Is this only available for 2.7.3 version of ChartJS?

Comment: No idea, refer to the chart.js documentation